# How to make @Cacheable return null when not found in cache but do not cache the result?

Tags: spring, caching, annotations

Following @Cacheable annotation

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="#isbn")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

- looks up in the cache based on the key
- if found return the result from cache
- if not found evaluates method
- updates the cache
- return the result

So that next time this method is called with same arguments it will be fetched from cache.

What I want instead is just to

- Look up in the cache based on key
- if found return the result from cache
- if not found return null

I don't want to update the cache in case of cache-miss, is there any way to do this using spring Annotation

Comment: This isn't really the use-case for the `@Cacheable` annotation, and it's not really a common use case at all, so I'd guess that no you can't do this with spring annotations, and that you'll have to write a `findBookInCache(ISBN isbn)` method yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I ended up with, trick was to use 'unless' to our advantage

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="#isbn", unless = "#result == null")
public Book findBookFromCache(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
{
    return null;
}
```

this method

- Looks up in the cache based on key
- if found return the result from cache
- if not found evaluates method that return null
- return value is matched with unless condition (which always return true)
- null value do not get cached
- null value is returned to caller

Comment: Hi, I have a scenario, where result comes as exception and unless in not configured in my code. So the resulted exception got cached to server. How to prevent this scenario using "unless"? Can i configure exceptions inside unless?